# Paralleling of 2 power supplies with different voltages

Tags: power, voltage, current, switch-mode-power-supply, parallel

I have 2 full bridge dc-dc converter from 12 to nearly 170 volts. each one are designed to 250 watts...

I am designing the transformers and is very complicated to make exactly equals by homemade and without machines... probably one voltage will be different to the other one, what if I parallel them?

I know that if I put 2 equal voltage batteries in parallel, the voltage will be the same and the current capability will be the double, and if I put them in series the voltages will be the double and the current capability will be the same. but what if the voltages are different in parallel? or what if the currents are different in series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paralleling converters isn't trivial.

If the voltages aren't equal, there won't be sharing going on - the supply with the higher voltage will deliver the entire current and the other(s) will deliver none. Setting the voltages identically is often impractical and as things drift and age over time, setpoint precision won't be maintained.

There needs to be a feedback mechanism in place to make sharing work and keep it working. In order to force converters to share, there are a few techniques commonly used in industry:

- **Droop sharing** - the output current of each converter is sensed and scaled and is fed into the voltage loop of the converter, causing the output voltage to decrease as the current being supplied increases. Lighter load means higher voltage which means it takes more of the load, which reduces the voltage - the system will settle into (relative) equilibrium
- **Forced sharing** - each converter generates a signal proportional to its output current and these signals are all tied together externally. The highest signal dominates. Each unit senses its output current and compares it with the forced sharing signal, feeding into the voltage loop to slightly increase or decrease the output voltage until the internal current signal matches the external bus. Once this happens, all the converters are equally sharing the load.

The current loops in both these examples must be designed not to interfere with the voltage loops (usually by setting their crossover frequencies an order of magnitude lower than that of the voltage loops).

Now if you want to get fancy, you can force a minutely small imbalance in the sharing so that the converters don't share equally - this can work when paralleling a lower capacity supply with a higher one (so long as you don't care about redundancy).

Putting converters in series is a little simpler (usually) - so long as neither rail collapses, you'll get the sum of the voltages out. No fancy feedback needed.

Some references: [Unitrode/TI](https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/SLUP094.pdf), [Blogspot.com](http://power-topics.blogspot.com/2008/03/droop-mode-current-share.html).

Comment: do you have any reference pdf or application note where I could understand a little better whar you are saying to me and learn how to do the drop sharing and the forced sharing.

Answer (score 2):

In series the current cannot be different.  That is one of the basic laws underlying electronics.  Suppose you have two voltage sources in series with a load R.  The current across R would be (V1 + V2)/R.  This current would flow through both of your voltage sources.  If one source is not capable of supplying sufficient current, the voltage it produces will decrease to a level commensurate with the maximum current it can supply.

In the case of parallel supplies with different voltages, you can expect that the the supply with the smaller output should sink some current from the higher voltage supply.  This can lead to undesirable behavior.  For this reason, you should put some reasonable resistor to ground at each output to ensure the supplies can sink sufficient current created by unequal voltages.